# alert message on button click and text changes in the fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, textbox, alert

I have one scenario to resolve. I have 2 text boxes for first name, last name and one button to save those fields. On the page load, we're filling 
those text fields with some data from the database, When we changed the text in any of those text fields and click on "Save" button,  we need to display a message/alert like

```
"You're about change the name of the person, john, smith to Daniel, clark". Do you wanna proceed?
```

If user responses to message/alert with Yes, then only we should allow those changes to save.

Code Snippets:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtfirstName"  runat="server" required="true" caption="First Name:" ></asp:TextBox>                           
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtlastName"  runat="server" caption="Last Name:"></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server"  Text="Save" CausesValidation="False"  />&nbsp;
```

Behind:

we need to call this code behind only after user chooses to change the name

```
 Protected Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
```

If the text fields are same, we no need to display any acknowledgement message. 
Can you please let me know how to do to this one.?

Comment: You don't call an event like that, create another method that has your save code in it and then call that, not a button click event.

Comment: <form onsubmit="return confirm('You're about change the name of the person, john, smith to Daniel, clark". Do you wanna proceed?');"> try this

Comment: Before showing the message do you need to requery the database to confirm the names have changed ?   or can you put the original values into a hidden field and just compare old and new based on that display the pop up ?

Comment: I can put those names into Hidden Fields to compare..  @EJD

Comment: Sorry I did not get back to you earlier

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are looking for :)

The JavaScript is formatted so you can easily read it.  You would typically put the JavaScript on 1 line or you could create a function and just call the function.

Also look up the confirm() JavaScript you can give your pop up a proper title and their are other options.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">

</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnfirstName" runat="server" Value="name" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnlastName" runat="server" Value="last" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtfirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtlastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" runat="server" 
        OnClientClick="if(document.getElementById('hdnfirstName').value !== document.getElementById('txtfirstName').value || 
                      document.getElementById('hdnlastName').value !== document.getElementById('txtlastName').value){

                            if (confirm('You\'re about change the name of the ' + 
                                         document.getElementById('hdnlastName').value + ', ' + 
                                         document.getElementById('hdnfirstName').value + ' to ' + 
                                         document.getElementById('txtlastName').value + ', ' + 
                                         document.getElementById('txtfirstName').value + 
                                         '. Do you wanna proceed?')) 
                            {
                                return true; 
                            } else { 
                                return false; 
                            }
                      } else {
                        return true;
                      }" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The confirm popup can also be replaced with a JQuery Popup since there are so many out there to choose from the answer would be too broad to answer.  You have the framework.

Comment: i wrote another question for the issues with this answer. Please find this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081136/javascript-runtime-error-the-value-of-the-property-confirmfunction-is-null-or]